# Issue with jquery scroll event

Tags: jquery

i am working with scroll event in which on scroll down on certain position a div should be popped up which is working fine but i am having an issue and that is i can see that div on every page of my website i want that only on one page on which i called the jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = window.location.href;
                var n = url.includes("schedule");
                if (n) {
                    if ($("#table-1").length) {
                        var fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed", parent.parent.document);
                        fixedHeader.find("thead").remove();
                        var header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
                        header.appendTo(fixedHeader);

                        var headers = $('#header-fixed thead tr', parent.parent.document);
                        var widths = [];
                        $('#table-1 > thead > tr').find("th").each(function () {
                            widths.push($(this).width());
                        });
                        for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
                            headers.find("th").eq(i).width((widths[i]));
                        }
                        $(window.parent.parent).bind("scroll", function () {
                            var offset = $(this).scrollTop();
                            if (offset > 640) {
                                if (n) {
                                    fixedHeader.show();
                                }
                                else
                                    fixedHeader.hide();
                            }
                            else if (offset < 640)
                                fixedHeader.hide();
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                    fixedHeader.hide();
            });
```

This is my jquery code 
Please help me with this 
Look at these images to see what actually happening 
[This is the image of that page where i wanted to float the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO37p.png)

[And it is showing on this page as well where i don't want to float](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7E1i.png)

I tried several things but nothing is working for me 
please help me

Comment: `fixedHeader` should be decared a higher level (scope).

Comment: I have done that as well but no luck